# Identifying forged queries to the server / allowing only UI-made queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, token, usability

Is there an easy/intuitive way to develop the logics so certain front-end/client-side **queries** to the server are **only allowed when built via the front-end app**, as opposite of someone using the session cookies to make their own forged queries?

- so to say a way to identify if a query has been handmade and have the server returning `0` results in that case?

We are on a `ruby` platform... so any `gem` solution to look at could help as well.

Comment: There is no silver bullet solution to this problem but a multitude of measures you can take to discourage such practices. Try looking at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html particularly the CSRF section although someone determined to mess with you can bypass all of these measures. Unless you build some custom, intricate request validation system.